# Symfony 6 y php 8.1

Tags: php, symfony

Estoy haciendo el proyecto de "guestbook" que tienen en la página de symfony pero cada comando que ejecuto me dice que el ejemplo está diseñado para php 8.1 y tengo instalado php 8.2 desde XAMP.
Cómo hago para instalar e indicar a symfony que utilice la versios 8.1 de php.

Gracias

Comment: esto no es un problema de programacion es un problema de superusuario ...

Comment: Puedes cambiar a la versión 8.2 actualizando el archivo `composer.json` del proyecto, en el apartado `require` , cambiar el valor de la entrada llamada `php`